# Use the Magento Test Automation Framework (MTAF) on a site with htaccess protection?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, phpunit

I want to run a test on a Magento installation that is protected with a htaccess password. How can I do that without entering the password each time the test is started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setup conditions in your .htaccess file for when the password prodection (basic auth) should protect.

For example, the config (.htaccess) below will: Allow access from the IP-address 123.45.67.12 but restrict access (prompt for username and password) when requested from any other IP-address.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName “Sorry, Restricted Area!”
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Allow from 123.45.67.890
Satisfy Any
```

Comment: Can I also add an exception looking at the URL that made the request? Something like **if(url.matches(some regex))**? Or can I evaluate query parameters?

Comment: I tried your approach and entered the servers IP, problem is that now anybody seems to be able to access the page? The IP I enter there, is that the IP of the caller? What if I call the URL like this: http://91.234.145.66/something/? Thats the servers IP, so if I enter this in the htaccess, will it allow access for everybody using the URL for calling? I hope you get what I mean.